# Should STL map::insert support move semantics with move_iterators?

Tags: c++11, dictionary, stl, move, move-semantics

I have a large amount of data to load into a `map` from file, which is already in sorted order (because it was serialized from the map).
I've discovered it is faster to first load the data into a `vector`, and then bulk-load into a `map` with `insert`. This saves just over a second in a 19sec load time.

The `value_type` is a structure that contains vectors of other structures. I don't need the `vector` after the load completes, so I use `move_iterator`s in my call to `map::insert`. Using MSVC 2015 (VC14), the data isn't moved into the map, but instead is copied via `const_reference` deep inside the STL code.

Is this a standard-compliant implementation, to ignore the moving of data?

```
template<typename Stream, typename Key, typename Type, typename Traits, typename Allocator>
bool const read(Stream &is, std::map<Key, Type, Traits, Allocator> &map)
{
    size_t size;
    read(is, size);

    std::vector<std::pair<Key, Type>> items(size);
    for (size_t i=0; i<size; ++i)
    {
        auto &item = items[i];
        if (!read(is, item.first)  ||  !read(is, item.second))
            return false;
    }
    map.insert(std::make_move_iterator(items.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(items.end()));

    return !!is;
}
```

I've overcome the problem replacing the `map.insert` with

```
for (auto &item : items)
    map.insert(std::move(item));
```

but it isn't so neat, but does save another 0.6 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a standard-compliant implementation, to ignore the moving of data?

The standard says for that `insert()` function:

> *Requires:* `value_type` shall be `EmplaceConstructible` into `X` from `*i`.

So it must be possible to construct the `value_type` from the iterator's `reference` type, which in this case is an rvalue-reference. That means you can use move-only (i.e. non-copyable) key types and mapped types and as long as the iterator returns rvalues that can be converted to the map's `value_type` it must work.

The constructor `std::pair<const Key, Type>::pair<K2, T2>(pair<K2, T2>&&)` should be used to construct the values into the map from the rvalues that come from the iterators.

This works for me with GCC, and with the latest VC++ using an online compiler:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

struct MoveOnly {
  MoveOnly() = default;
  MoveOnly(MoveOnly&&) = default;
};

bool operator<(const MoveOnly&, const MoveOnly&) { return false; }

template<typename Key, typename Type, typename Traits, typename Allocator>
void read(std::map<Key, Type, Traits, Allocator> &map)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<Key, Type>> items(1);
    map.insert(std::make_move_iterator(items.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(items.end()));
}

int main()
{
  std::map<MoveOnly, MoveOnly> m;
  read(m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have specified your own Move Constructor or Move Assigment Operator, then you should mark it as 'noexcept'. Otherwise standard containers will copy elements.
Check docs here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec

Comment: That's true for `std::vector` but shouldn't matter for inserting into a map.

Comment: well that's not true. I believe they mentioned std::vector just as an example :) here is another link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor . Notes part says: To make strong exception guarantee possible, user-defined move constructors should not throw exceptions. In fact, standard containers typically rely on std::move_if_noexcept to choose between move and copy when container elements need to be relocated.

Comment: @klimov:  <big laugh>  Be careful, you're arguing with the guy who maintains the gcc std::lib for a living! :-)

Comment: @klimov, `map` uses `move_if_noexcept` in its move assignment operator, but typically not when inserting from a range of iterators (when it isn't relocating any elements). You can modify the example in my answer to have a throwing move constructor and a copy constructor, and see that it still moves. Or search the standard for mention of `is_nothrow_move_constructible` in Clause 23, and compare [vector.modifiers] to [map.modifiers]. Your advice is good in general, but not relevant to this specific question.